# Functions words are strike when called in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
btn_filePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       myFileIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       myFileIntent.setType("*/*");
       startActivityForResult(myFileIntent,10);
    }
});
```

`startActivityForResult` has a strike through it and I don't know why.

Comment: A strikethrough is the default way of indicating that a method, class, or other element is deprecated.

Comment: may i know why its depreciated?